# How do you merge two tables and keep the column they share while adding the other columns they don't?

Tags: mysql

Say I have these two tables:

```
+--------+-----+ 
| bookID | Jan | 
+--------+-----+ 
| 1094   | 1   | 
| 1058   | 1   | 
| 984    |  1  | 
+--------+-----+ 
+--------+-----+ 
| bookID | Dec | 
+--------+-----+ 
| 1      | 1   | 
| 2      | 1   | 
+--------+-----+
```

I would like to get:

```
+--------+-----+-----+ 
| bookID | Jan | Dec |
+--------+-----+-----+ 
| 1094   | 1   | 0   | 
| 1058   | 1   | 0   | 
| 984    | 1   | 0   | 
| 1      | 0   | 1   | 
| 2      | 0   | 1   | 
+--------+-----+-----+
```

I was thinking of using join on the id and using union to get bookID's that aren't in both tables, but it seemed inefficient because I would have to do the same for the rest of the months.

Would there be a better way to achieve this from this table:

```
+----+--------+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+ 
| id | bookID | studentID | checkOutDate | returnDate |  dueDate   | extended | 
+----+--------+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+ 
| 1  | 25     | 1         | 2019-12-09   |  NULL      | 2019-12-25 | 0        | 
| 2  | 357    | 2         | 2019-12-09   | NULL       | 2019-12-25 | 0        | 
| 3  | 365    | 3         | 2019-12-09   | NULL       | 2019-12-25 | 0        | 
| 4  | 984    | 8         | 2019-12-09   | NULL       | 2019-12-25 | 0        |
| 5  | 1094   | 1         | 2019-12-09   | NULL       | 2019-12-25 | 0        | 
| 11 | 99     | 2         | 2019-01-11   | NULL       | 2019-12-10 | 0        | 
| 12 | 1      | 2         | 2019-01-24   | NULL       | 2019-01-11 | 0        | 
+----+--------+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+
```

I want to display a list of books, and, for each book, 13 columns: 12 columns showing the number of checkouts for each month and a 13th column to display total year checkouts for the book.

Comment: it's easier to show example queries if you tell us what the table names are

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Comment: Please just ask 1 question per post. The first question here is a frequent duplicate. (You describe a full outer join.) Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left hand side of the answer. And feel free to upvote it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly straight forward (but a little verbose) to do from the original table using a CASE to get the count for each month as a column and GROUP BY to get a row by book and year.

```
SELECT 
  bookID, YEAR(checkoutDate) `year`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(checkoutDate) =  1 THEN 1 END) `jan`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(checkoutDate) =  2 THEN 1 END) `feb`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(checkoutDate) =  3 THEN 1 END) `mar`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(checkoutDate) =  4 THEN 1 END) `apr`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(checkoutDate) =  5 THEN 1 END) `may`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(checkoutDate) =  6 THEN 1 END) `jun`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(checkoutDate) =  7 THEN 1 END) `jul`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(checkoutDate) =  8 THEN 1 END) `aug`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(checkoutDate) =  9 THEN 1 END) `sep`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(checkoutDate) = 10 THEN 1 END) `oct`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(checkoutDate) = 11 THEN 1 END) `nov`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(checkoutDate) = 12 THEN 1 END) `dec`,
  COUNT(*) `year total checkouts`
FROM myTable
GROUP BY bookID, YEAR(checkoutDate)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09db11/1)